# Why does data.table change the key after a transformation in j?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with a two-column key (id, date) and one or more columns of data. Some of the data might have missing values so I am using na.locf() from zoo to fill it in. I have noticed this operation changes the key in my data.table and I need to re-key it for subsequent joins. Why is this happening and in what other situations can I expect such behavior?

You can use the code below to reproduce the issue.

Thanks!

```
require(zoo)
d <- data.table(id = rep(1:2, each = 5), date = rep(1:5, 2), value = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA, 6,7,8,9,10))
setkey(d, id, date)
x <- d[, lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = 1), by = 'id']

key(d)
key(x)
```

Comment: Well, how can data.table know that the new `date` column is still sorted? What I find more suprising is that `d[, names(d)[-1] := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = 1), by = 'id']` completely removes the key.

Comment: I would think the default behavior would be to rekey by the columns in the key, just want to make sure it's not rather than something else is going on.

Comment: No, that a column is a key means that the data.table is sorted by it. If you create a new column (either your way or by reference) that means it's not sure if the data.table is sorted by it. That you have to rekey explicitly is a feature because sorting costs performance and sometimes you don't want the data.table to be keyed with the new column even if it's name is the same as of an old column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
x <- copy(d)
x[, (3:length(x)) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, maxgap = 1), by = 'id', .SDcols=3:length(x)]
key(x)
```

Results in:

```
[1] "id"   "date"
```

And `x`:

```
    id date value
 1:  1    1     1
 2:  1    2     2
 3:  1    3     1
 4:  1    4     2
 5:  1    5     1
 6:  2    1     6
 7:  2    2     7
 8:  2    3     8
 9:  2    4     9
10:  2    5    10
```

This assumes you don't need `na.locf` to be applied on the `date` column.  Since you're not changing that column using `:=` on the other columns preserves the key on the table.

Also, I had to change your use of `na.locf` `na.rm` to the default as otherwise that doesn't do anything.